# MySql Workbench not responding?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to start the server , MySql Workbench shows me this error
[image: Not responding]

In the Services ,MYSQL80 is already running [image]

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Have you checked to see if you are using the correct credentials/user id/group when starting the server?